# Form insertion into database not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I'm trying to get a text area's value inserted asynchrnously into my database, however it keeps redirecting to the PHP processing page, and echoing a result there. **How would I get it to echo the result of the PHP script on the current HTML page?**

JS:

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
$.post( $("#text").attr("action"), $("#text :input").serializeArray(), 
function(info) { $("#result").html(info);});
});

$("#text").submit( function(){
return false;
})
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "UPDATE text 
        SET text_content = ? WHERE (id = 40) AND (number = $Number);";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
            {
                header("Location: ../create_text.php?error&prepare1111");
                exit();
            }
            else
            { 
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $content);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                $connection->close();
                echo "successfully saved";
            }
```

HTML:

```
<form type="text" method="post" onSubmit="return validateText(); toHTML();" action="processing.php" id="text">
            <textarea name="content" rows="45" id="auto-expand" class="text-box" type="text"><?php echo stripslashes($content) ?></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="updated" value="<?php echo $updated ?>">
            <button type="submit" id="sub" name="submit">Save</button>
            <button type="button" onClick="validateText(); toHTML();">Check</button>
            <span id="result"></span>
        </form>
```

Any help would be **so great**! :)

Comment: `$("#sub").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Remove the inline handlers, and attach the first function to `#text.submit` event, and then add `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I removed the inline functions for the text form, still redirected to PHP page

Comment: remove inline, remove `$("#text").submit( function(){` whole thing. if that still doesn't work, verify jquery is properly loaded before all these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try preventDefault:

```
$("#text").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(, still redirects to the PHP script and echoes there

Comment: @akemedis What if you to change type="submit" to type="button" for the button?

Comment: then it does not get inserted into the database

Comment: @akemedis Try `$(document).on('submit', '#text', function( event ) {` instead of `$("#text").submit( function(e){`. Worked for me.